# How to add custom logic for authorizing and authentication in OAuth2.0 with Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, spring-security-oauth2

While authorizing and generating access token using OAuth 2.0 implemented with Spring boot.. we `implement` `UserEntity` with `UserDetails` in which we return respective fields from methods `getUsername()` and `getPassword()` which is gets called while authorizing and authenticating. I tried to find APIs that will help me achieve this.. but i got no breakthrough yet. How can we enable OAuth 2.0 for **single username and multiple passwords?**. Thanks!